# Assigning proper vlan id tag to a QEMU-KVM Centos 7 virtual machine

Tags: centos7, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, vlan, qemu

I have a Centos 7 QEMU-KVM virtual machine located at a Centos 7 physical server. Both are in a network that uses vlan ids. Also the Network Admin Guy told me to assign the VLanId 33 to the Virtual machine. Because of this, the virtual machine can not have internet access unless I assign this VM the proper VLanId. At the host I also installed QEMU-KVM using:

```
sudo yum install qemu-kvm qemu-img virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer bridge-utils
```

I also added my account to the libvirt group to be able to run the virt-manager using ssh with:

```
usermod --append --groups libvirt `whoami`
```

From:

```
https://serverfault.com/questions/868093/vms-on-a-kvm-host-with-tagged-vlans
```

I saw:
"tagging VMs isn't inside the VM itself, it's by creating tagged interfaces on the host, creating bridges on top of those tagged interfaces (so you have something like a tagged v-switch) and plugging the VMs into those tagged bridges"

So, I have some questions:

a) What I need to have installed in the Centos 7 physical host to create tagged interfaces within the host itself?

b) How do I create bridges on top of those tagged interfaces?

c) How do I plug the QEMU-KVM Virtual Machine into those tagged bridges?

d) Is there any software/hardware I could use to experiment with the solutions to a)-c)? I do not want to put in risk the production Centos 7 host to test the needed configuration.

Thx

Comment: Did you use libvirt?

Comment: yes I do.... I also posted the cmd I used o install QEMU-KVM